# Rails 5 ApplicationRecord inheritance with exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want all my models to inherit a validation present in my ApplicationRecord file except the `user` model. Is there a way to achieve that?
This is the line `validates :user_id, presence: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend putting that in `ApplicationRecord` since it's meant to be the parent of all modules, but if you really want to do it:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, presence: true, unless: 'self.class.to_s == "User"'
  ...
end
```

But i strongly suggest against it. This would make your code counter intuitive and future developers would have trouble understanding why it functions like that. Not to mention any future records you create, you explicitly have to set `presence: false`.

Comment: While I agree somewhat to your suggestion, user_id is definitely going to be in all my models. However this solution doesn't work because user_id IS NOT a column in user table, hence it throws an error.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal if you must, i guess so. I've updated the code and tested it.

Comment: I'll test it when I wake up. Time to hit the bed. Thanks for the quick reply :)